# Linking library and undefined reference to function in JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, static-linking

I'm trying to use two different libraries in my JNI code:

I've tried to compile them with the following android.mk file:

```
TOP_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Lib native-audio-jni
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

APP_PLATFORM := android-19

LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native-audio-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-audio-jni.c \ wavfile.c
# for native audio
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lOpenSLES
# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
# for native asset manager
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#For libsndfile-android
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_PATH)/libsndfile-android

OGG_ROOT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/deps/libogg/include
VORBIS_ROOT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/deps/libvorbis/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_EXTERNAL_LIBS
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(OGG_ROOT) $(VORBIS_ROOT)

LOCAL_MODULE   := sndfile

OGG_SRC_FILES := deps/libogg/src/bitwise.c deps/libogg/src/framing.c
V_SRC := deps/libvorbis/src
VORBIS_SRC_FILES := $(V_SRC)/analysis.c $(V_SRC)/floor0.c   $(V_SRC)/lsp.c      $(V_SRC)/res0.c \
       $(V_SRC)/vorbisfile.c $(V_SRC)/bitrate.c $(V_SRC)/floor1.c $(V_SRC)/mapping0.c   $(V_SRC)/sharedbook.c   \
       $(V_SRC)/window.c $(V_SRC)/block.c   $(V_SRC)/info.c   $(V_SRC)/mdct.c   $(V_SRC)/smallft.c \
       $(V_SRC)/codebook.c  $(V_SRC)/lookup.c $(V_SRC)/psy.c  $(V_SRC)/synthesis.c \
       $(V_SRC)/envelope.c  $(V_SRC)/lpc.c  $(V_SRC)/registry.c $(V_SRC)/vorbisenc.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mat5.c windows.c G72x/g723_24.c G72x/g72x.c \
       G72x/g723_40.c G72x/g721.c G72x/g723_16.c \
       float32.c chanmap.c test_endswap.c rf64.c sndfile.c htk.c dither.c \
       test_log_printf.c txw.c ms_adpcm.c ima_adpcm.c flac.c aiff.c \
       wav.c macbinary3.c mat4.c pcm.c caf.c \
       audio_detect.c id3.c alaw.c macos.c file_io.c broadcast.c double64.c \
       raw.c test_broadcast_var.c \
       g72x.c command.c chunk.c avr.c sd2.c voc.c test_audio_detect.c \
       mpc2k.c gsm610.c dwd.c \
       interleave.c common.c test_strncpy_crlf.c sds.c pvf.c paf.c au.c \
       test_float.c \
       vox_adpcm.c ulaw.c strings.c svx.c test_conversions.c rx2.c nist.c \
       GSM610/code.c GSM610/gsm_destroy.c \
       GSM610/gsm_decode.c GSM610/short_term.c GSM610/gsm_create.c \
       GSM610/decode.c GSM610/gsm_option.c \
       GSM610/long_term.c GSM610/table.c GSM610/rpe.c GSM610/preprocess.c \
       GSM610/gsm_encode.c GSM610/lpc.c \
       GSM610/add.c dwvw.c wav_w64.c wve.c ogg.c ogg_vorbis.c w64.c test_file_io.c\
       ircam.c xi.c ima_oki_adpcm.c \
       $(OGG_SRC_FILES) $(VORBIS_SRC_FILES)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := sndfilelib
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sndfile

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When i compile everything works good and I get my two shared libraries (.so) in the respective architectural folders.

The problem is that, when I try to use a function that is defined in one of the .h files contained in the second library (the local static one) I get the error "undefined reference to function".

So I think there should be a way to link this static library to the non static one.

I've already tried to import the .h file in the .m file where I'm trying to use the function but nothing change

please help me and thanks for your time

Comment: Can you compile sndfilelib? I have compiled but I can't use sf_open in code C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the declaration of the ***sndfile*** module at the top of the file and then edit your ***native-audio-jni*** module by adding this:

```
...
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := sndfilelib
```

or, alternatively, this:

```
...
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sndfile
```